How to use next/link component in independent npm-package
I decided to move some parts of my next application to independent npm-packages.
For example I made the package @my-scope/menu and put it to my local registry
import Link from 'next/link';
export function Menu({items}: {items: Array<{ url: string, text: string }>}): JSX.Element {
    return <ul>
        {items.map(item => <li key={url}><Link href={url}>{text}</Link></li>)}
    </ul>
}

But, after I've tried to use this package inside my main application
import { Menu } from '@my-scope/menu

function MyPage() {
    const items = [{ url: '/a', title: 'a' }, { url: '/b', title: 'b' }];
    return <Menu items={items} />;
}

I've faced an error NextRouter was not mounted.
Documentation tells me only how to use my component inside storybook/tests and how to migrate to new version of next routing (I use 13.2)
Could somebody help me. I'm absolutely confused and have no idea how to do this
